# Reading N bits from a GPIO Pin Based on Baud Rate PiGPIO

Tags: python, serialization, gpio, pigpio

Pretty much as I described in the title, I am attempting to read the next N bits appearing at a GPIO pin following a call. For context, I am setting a chip select (CS) enable and after two clock cycles I expect a 10 bit sequence. I'm not very worried in this moment about ensuring I have the exactly 10 bits, so much as I'd rather be sure I'm atleast getting the 10 I need, even if I also get some stuff around the edges. I've been using PiGPIO and trying to using the bb_serial_read functionality, however I've been having trouble fulling understanding the functionality of this tool since the documentation isn't too specific and I don't have much experience with bit banging.

I was approaching it this way:

```
pi.hardware_clock(CLOCK_PIN, CLOCK_FREQ)
pi.bb_serial_read_open(DATA_PIN, CLOCK_FREQ)

enable_CS()
(count, val) = pi.bb_serial_read(DATA_PIN)
disable_CS()
```

After which I would attempt to convert the value returned to a binary string. The primary obstacles I've run into surrounds the arguments to bb_serial_read_open, as the bb_serial_read returns a bytearray which tends to look like '\x00\x00\x01\x00' or something similar, the values tend to vary. If I want to ensure I am getting some number of consecutive bits, what is the appropriate way to convert this to the raw binary? Also, is there a way to flush the cyclic buffer the the bit bang protocol is storing its values in? I'm pretty sure this is a simple problem, but I've been back and forth between documentation and example code with no luck for a while now.

Comment: You described a task that Real Time OS should handle. Nothing suggests you have a proper environment (that said, it will be always error prone, because your OS and especially Python may not guarantee any timings). So, be sure you run something like Zephyr and driver there for your needs.

Comment: Hmm, Im more familiar with microcontroller work, was trying to emulate functionality I can achieve there on a Pi. Was mostly out if curiosity to see if I could do it. Ill look into Zephyr and see if its feasible for my application. As more of a theoretical question, would there be a theoretically high enough sample rate to guarantee that I could downsample to retrieve the original signal?

Comment: In RTOS yes, you may get a guarantee of the certain time slice. Otherwise, in a General Purpose (GP) OS there is no such guarantee, it might work in 99% of the time, but fail badly at some point under a certain circumstances... Microcontroller approach (OS-less or RTOS-based, like Zephyr, yes it was designed for microcontrollers) is always a RT-ish one. That's why it's hard to achieve the same on GP OS. You may try with Linux RT, btw.

Comment: Looks like I might just have to grab an ADC chip with a dedicated spi or i2c interface. Oh well, I had the other chip available and it was a fun thing to mess with

Comment: That's right direction. You may check _drivers/iio/adc_ folder in the Linux kernel source tree to see what kind of ADCs are already supported in the best possible way.